# Модельное окно работает только из первой строчки таблицы

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap, thymeleaf

Создал модельное окно, которое  уточняло подтверждение действия.
Так как таблицу заполняю из БД через thymeleaf, то получается, что кнопка из таблицы активна только в первой строчке. условные 2ая, 3ая, etc..кнопки на нажатие не реагируют

Script:

```
<script>
        $(function () {
        $("#btn2").click(function () {
                $("#myModal2").modal('show');
            });
        });
</script>
```

Сама таблица:

```
 <div align="center" th:each="el : ${docks}">
    <table class="table table-active table-striped">
        <tbody class="thead-light">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p><a href="#myModal2" id="btn2" class="btn btn-danger">X</a></p>
                <div id="myModal2" class="modal fade">
                    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <h4 class="modal-title">Подтвердите действия</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <th:block th:text="'TestTest ' + ${el.dockNumber}"></th:block>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Закрыть</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" >Сохранить изменения</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td align="left" th:text="${el.dockNumber}"></td>
```

JQuery и Bootstrap.min.css - подключены

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$("#btn2")`  выбирает максимум один элемент, исходя из предположения об уникальности `id` элемента на странице.

```
 <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn2">X</a></p>
 <div class="modal fade myModal2">

 $(".btn2").click(function () {
   $(this).closest("td").find(".myModal2").modal('show');
 });
```

Comment: не силен в JS от слова совсем, подскажите, как сделать, чтобы он брал все элементы из таблицы?

Comment: попробовал Ваш код, к сожалению, не помогло, с ним даже первая строчка становится неактивна, либо же я что то сделал не так

Comment: @koSHa Вы что-то сделали не так.